# Disable end date not more than 10 day calendar javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i want to know disable end date not more than 10 day. this value select start date dynamic

**example:**
select startdate 12/21/2018 
select enddate (select date more than 10 day) 12/30/2018

startdate dynamic to enddate 10 day moreover disable all calendar length 1-10 day / min1 - max10

```js
<script>
    $("#dateFrom").datepicker({
        "onSelect": function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var dayAfter = input.datepicker("getDate");
            dayAfter.setDate(dayAfter.getDate() + +10);
            $("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dayAfter);
            $("#dateTo").datepicker("refresh");
        }
    });
    $("#dateTo").datepicker({
        "onSelect": function () {
            var input = $(this);
            $("#dateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", input.datepicker("getDate"));
            $("#dateFrom").datepicker("refresh");
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div> <span>startdate :</span>

    <input type="text" class="datepicker-to" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" />
</div>
<div> <span>enddate :</span>

    <input type="text" class="datepicker-to" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you want the startDate and endDate within 10 days.you can try this:

```
  `$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
  "onSelect": function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var dayAfter = input.datepicker("getDate");
    dayAfter.setDate(dayAfter.getDate() + 10);
    $("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", input.datepicker("getDate"));
    $("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dayAfter);
    $("#dateTo").datepicker("refresh");
  }
});
$("#dateTo").datepicker({
  "onSelect": function() {
    /*     var input = $(this);
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", input.datepicker("getDate"));
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker("refresh"); */
  }
});`
```

I have test; it's ok; look my jsfiddle:[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/ananis/sdq26rhs/)

Comment: one question. please sample input type="date" not use datepicker

Comment: @Tanaphon Prayoonprasop you can try , use input type="date" props 'min' and 'max'

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery Datepicker? This has a option for it.

```
// Getter
var maxDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+1m +1w" );
```

Link to the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate).

Comment: no not working enddate reference this value startdate

Comment: Is it correct that you want to let the user select a start date. Then when they open #dateTo, that they get a selectable range from selected date to selected date + 10 days ?